# Adding time values produces 0:00:00

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

```
in-time is     9:36:00
out-time is   18:53:00
hours worked = 9:17:00
required hrs = 9:30:00 (a specification)
```

The difference between hrs req and hrs worked is = -0:13:00.  Formula used:

```
=IF(D2>E2,"+","-")&TEXT(ABS(D2-E2),"h:mm:ss")
```

I want to add the difference between `hrs req` and `hrs worked` and there are many records.  Sometimes the employee worked extra time, in which case a positive value is displayed, like `+1:14:00`.  Sometimes he worked less time and a negative value is displayed, like `-0:13:00`.  But when I add these records, it shows 0:00:00.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're doing math and then converting the result to text. When you sum a bunch of text, you get zero.

A simple way to do this is to use an extra column.  Do the time difference calculations: `=D2-E2` and leave it as a number.  Sum those results to get the net difference.  Display the results in an adjacent column.  For example, say the differences are in column F.  The display can be in column G:

```
 =IF(F2<0,"-","+")&TEXT(ABS(F2),"h:mm:ss")
```

The formula would apply to the net, also.  Note that I reversed your test for the +/- so that zero doesn't show as a negative.  You can hide the raw numbers column if you don't want to see it.